# Display summary information on command when running Meta-x

Tags: completion, commands, help, m-x

Since I'm new to `GNU Emacs` (version 26.1 running on `Debian Stable`) I'd like to get some information when invoking a command using `Meta-x`.  Currently I'm only able to see a list of possible completions but I have to guess what the commands are actually doing (although, to be honest, many of them are named very intuitively).

As an explanation: when I'm running

`pac` `<tab>` `li` `<tab>` `<tab>`

the following lines are shown in my minibuffer

```
Possible completions are:
package-list-packages
package-list-packages-no-fetch
```

but I'd like the following functionality

```
Possible completions are:
package-list-packages               Display a list of packages.
package-list-packages-no-fetch      Display a list of packages.
```

or something similar.

Is there a way to get this option?  Additionally: can I do this without installing additional packages?

Comment: Not quite what you want but once you have a completion list, you can switch to that buffer, move point to one of the functions and press `C-h f RET` to get its doc string. Then, move point to the next function and repeat.

Comment: @nickd: thanks, that was not what I asked for but never the less good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) + [ivy-rich](https://github.com/Yevgnen/ivy-rich).

[The relevant section](https://github.com/Yevgnen/ivy-rich#22-counsel-m-x) of the documentation has this screenshot:

[image]

You need to include the following lines in your `init.el`:

```
(require 'ivy)
(ivy-mode 1)
(require 'ivy-rich)
(ivy-rich-mode 1)
(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'counsel-M-x)
```

Comment: @formin-martin: thanks a lot, that was it! I needed to include some lines in my `init.el` and added them to your answer, I hope that's fine.

Comment: @n0542344 You're welcome! It's absolutely fine, actually I didn't include them on purpose as the READMEs are sufficiently clear. You can also use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) to set up your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

With [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) such info is available anytime during completion (including for `M-x`), at the press of a key.

This feature, getting help on individual completion candidates, is described [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d%27Apropos#GetHelpOnCandidates).

Short summary: Use `C-M-mouse-2` to show help on the completion candidate you click in buffer `*Completions*`.  Or cycle to a candidate and use `C-M-RET` to show help on it.

In addition, short help for the current candidate (e.g. during cycling) is shown in the mode-line.  This is typically the first line of its doc string, or other relevant short info.

You can also show the full help on candidates (in buffer `*Help*`) as you cycle, by cycling with `C-M-down` or `C-M-up`, instead of just `down` or `up`.